# Como mudar a cor da borda de um TextBox em um app de Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, mobile, app, xaml, windows-mobile

Em uma determinada função do código do `.cs` em `C#` preciso mudar a cor da borda de um `TextBox`.
No meu `xaml` tenho o `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Name="txtResult" Text="resultado"/>
```

E no `cs` tenho a validação

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (int.Parse(txtResult.Text) == 1){
    //mudar a cor da borda para verde
    } else {
    //mudar a cor da borda para vermelho
    }
}
```

Como posso realizar essa mudança?

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade `BorderBrush` da classe `TextBox`:

```
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtResult.Text == "1")
        {
            this.txtResult.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtResult.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```